# VBA Loop through column and find value in specified range

Tags: vba, for-loop

Thank you in advance. New to VBA and trying to teach myself in my spare time. I am hoping someone can provide me some code to build on.

I want to loop through column K and search for each cell in columns A:I. Then I want to select the whole row and cut to another sheet. This is the code I have written, it utilized activecell but as you can imagine I would like to avoid having to click the cell I want to search for every time I execute the Macro. Especially, if I have 150 values in column K.

```
Sub Lineups()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A2:I1501")

Dim ac As Range
Set ac = Application.ActiveCell

rng.Find(what:=ac).Select
ac.Interior.Color = 65535
Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row).Resize(1, 9).Cut
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1

Sheets("Lineups").Select
NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Cells(NextRow, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Sheets("Data").Select


End Sub
```

Picture of the Data Set is below.

[Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htB1G.png)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, thanks for the insight. I have code written already and will update this post.

Comment: Not clear what you try accomplishing, only reading the question and looking to your code... What is `ac` a cell From "K:K" column? Then, do you want finding/searching for it in all the sheet cells? Independent of column where it may be found? Even so, should we understand that only a unique occurrence will be found?

Comment: I wanted to say all the range ("A2:H1501") columns, not in a specific one? Do you need copying the cells format, too?

Comment: Yes, ac is a cell from "K:K. Yes, I want to search for the selected cell in columns "A:I" and find the first occurrence starting from the top. There could be hundreds of occurrences but I only need the first one. I hope that helps.

Comment: When you try cutting a part of a row, I suppose you want copying that part and clear that range contents. Would such an understanding be correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. I want to cut the row instead of copy because I dont want to use the row twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code. Not tested, but it should work. Selecting, activating is not ta good habit. It only consumes Excel resources without bringing any benefit. Then, coloring, copying each cell/range during iteration, takes time and makes code slower. The best way is to build `Union` ranges and color/copy at the end of the code, at once:

```
Sub Lineups()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, ac As Range, rngCol As Range
 Dim lastRow As Long, rngCopy As Range, arrRng, i As Long

 Set ws = ActiveSheet 'use there the sheet you want processing (probably Sheets("Data")
 'lastRow = ws.Range("K" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'the last row in column K:K
 lastRow = 1501 'if you need last cell in K:K, uncomment the line above and comment this one
 Set rng = ws.Range("A2:H" & lastRow)

 For i = 2 To lastRow
    Set ac = rng.Find(what:=ws.Range("K" & i).value, After:=ws.Range("A2"), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not ac Is Nothing Then     'if a match has been found:
        If rngCol Is Nothing Then 'build the range with matching cells, to be colored at the end, at once:
            Set rngCol = ws.Range("K" & i)
        Else
            Set rngCol = Union(rngCol, ws.Range("K" & i))
        End If
        If rngCopy Is Nothing Then 'build the range with matching cells, to be colored at the end, at once:
            Set rngCopy = ws.Range("A" & ac.row, ws.cells(ac.row, "i"))
        Else
            Set rngCopy = Union(rngCopy, ws.Range("A" & ac.row, ws.cells(ac.row, "i")))
        End If
    End If
 Next i
 If Not rngCol Is Nothing Then rngCol.Interior.Color = 65535 ' color the interior of the matching cells in K:K

 'Copy the necessary range in sheet "Lineups" and clear the copied range:
 Dim wsL As Worksheet, nextRow As Long
 Set wsL = Sheets("Lineups")

 nextRow = wsL.cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row + 1
 If Not rngCopy Is Nothing Then 'if at least a match has been found:
     rngCopy.Copy wsL.cells(nextRow, 1) 'copy the union range at once
     rngCopy.ClearContents              'clear contents of the union range at once
 End If
End Sub
```

I am leaving now my office. If something does not work as you need, or you do  not understand the code, do not hesitate to ask or specify what is happening against what you need. I will be able to reply after some hours when I will be at home.

**Edited**:

Please, test the next version and send some feedback:

```
Sub Lineups_()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, rngSearch As Range, ac As Range, rngCol As Range
 Dim lastRow As Long, rngCopy As Range, rngExcl As Range, i As Long, k As Long

 Set ws = ActiveSheet 'use there the sheet you want processing (probably Sheets("Data")
 lastRow = ws.Range("K" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'the last row in column K:K
 ws.Range("K2:K" & lastRow).Interior.Color = xlNone 'clear interior color to see the changes (you can comment it, if not  necessary)
 Set rng = ws.Range("A2:H1501")
 Set rngSearch = rng 'set a so named search range, adapted by excluding of processed rows

 For i = 2 To lastRow
    Set ac = rngSearch.Find(what:=ws.Range("K" & i).Value, After:=rngSearch.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not ac Is Nothing Then      'if a match has been found:
        If rngCol Is Nothing Then 'build the range with matching cells, to be colored at the end, at once:
            Set rngCol = ws.Range("K" & i)
        Else
            Set rngCol = Union(rngCol, ws.Range("K" & i))
        End If
        If rngCopy Is Nothing Then 'build the range with matching cells, to be colored at the end, at once:
            Set rngCopy = ws.Range("A" & ac.Row, ws.Cells(ac.Row, "i")):
            Set rngExcl = ws.Range("A" & ac.Row) 'set the range to be excluded
        Else
            Set rngCopy = Union(rngCopy, ws.Range("A" & ac.Row, ws.Cells(ac.Row, "i")))
              Set rngExcl = Union(rngExcl, ws.Range("A" & ac.Row)) 'build the range to be excluded
        End If
    End If
    'build the string where to search for:
    Set rngSearch = InverseIntersect(rngSearch, rngExcl.EntireRow)
 Next i
 If Not rngCol Is Nothing Then rngCol.Interior.Color = 65535 ' color the interior of the matching cells in K:K

 'Copy the necessary range in sheet "Lineups" and clear the copied range:
 Dim wsL As Worksheet, nextRow As Long
 Set wsL = ws.Next ' Sheets("Lineups")

 nextRow = wsL.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 If Not rngCopy Is Nothing Then 'if at least a match has been found:
     rngCopy.Copy wsL.Cells(nextRow, 1) 'copy the union range at once
     rngCopy.ClearContents                   'clear contents of the union range at once
 End If
 MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub

Function InverseIntersect(bigRng As Range, rngExtract As Range) As Range
    Dim rng As Range, rngRow As Range

    For Each rngRow In bigRng.rows 'iterate between the range to be processed rows:
        If Intersect(rngRow, rngExtract) Is Nothing Then 'if iterated row intersects with range to be extracted:
                                                                         'creates a range only from rows which do not intersect
            If rng Is Nothing Then                       'Set the range as the current row
                Set rng = rngRow
            Else
                Set rng = Union(rng, rngRow)             'creates a Union between the previous existing range and the current row
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Set InverseIntersect = rng                           'set the function as the newly created range
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much FaneDuru. I will review it and try to digest as much as I can before reaching out. Really appreciate it.

Comment: This is excellent, I have been looking through it this evening. I am getting an error that I cannot figure out. If I have more than 99 rows in column "K" than I get an error that says "Method 'Range' Of Object '_Worksheet' failed" This is the code that throws the error `Set rng = wsD.Range("A2:H1501" & lastRow)`

Comment: Also, what is the reference to `arrRng` in the code? @FaneDuru

Comment: @safo2238 Such a code line does  not exist in the above answer... Please, try using the code exactly as it is and make modifications only after seeing it working. Such a way of using means a range to be set as "A2:H15011501" (supposing that `lastRow` is 1501 or similar), which exceeds the maximum existing number of rows in a sheet (1048576 )...

Comment: @safo2238 I forgot saying something about `arrRng` variable... When I start a project, I firstly make a plan (in my head) involving solution to be chosen, necessary variables etc. I initially thought that it is better to create such an array (due to the faster iteration comparing with a range) instead of the iteration of a range. But the difference in the way I did it does not justify using it and I only forgot to delete the variable. For huge ranges it could help a little, but for thousands of rows the influence should be minor.

Comment: That makes sense about the `arrRng` variable. I ran the code exactly as you wrote it and it works great if I define `lastrow = 1501`. If I define `lastRow = wsD.Range("K" & wsD.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` it skips rows in column "K".

Comment: One reason I wanted to move the cell range before moving onto the next iteration is because multiple rows of column "K" can be found in a single row of "A:H". I want each row of column "K" to have its own copy iteration. Does that make sense? If there are 150 rows in column "K" then I want to end up with 150 rows in Sheet "Lineups" when it is complete.

Comment: @safo2238 It cannot skip any row in K:K. `lastRow = wsD.Range("K" & wsD.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` returns the last cell having a value in column K:K. Not sure if I correctly understand this part: **multiple rows of column "K" can be found in a single row of "A:H"**... If many values from "K:K" can be found in the same row of "A:H" range, the above code will found all o them (their first occurrence). What you say makes sense only if you do not want **the same row to be returned for the following value to be matched**. Now, I asked you if **need copying the cells format**, but no answer...

Comment: @safo2238 Don't `K:K` and "A:H" have the same number of rows?

Comment: "A:H" will always have 1501 rows. Column K could potentially only have 20 rows or it might have 100 rows, but never more than 150. For example, if there are 100 rows in "K:K" I want the final product in `Sheets ("Lineups")` to have 100 rows. The way the code works now is there could be 100 rows in "K:K" but could only end up with 50 rows in `Sheets ("Lineups")` because as the code is looping down through column "K:K" it is finding the same row of "A:H". I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @safo2238 Then, use `lastRow` to calculate the rows in "K:K", differently build `rng` (as Range("A2:H1501"). I didn't see your data and (wrongly) supposed that both involved ranges have the same number of rows. It is clear only in a way... You din not say anything about this part of my comment: **What you say makes sense only if you do not want the same row to be returned for the following value to be matched**... If I will be able to understand what you really mean, the code can be adapted. It can memorize the 'used' rows in an array and skip them (in  a way) from the matching process.

Comment: @safo2238 A previous comment repeats a clarification requirement: **Now, I asked you if need copying the cells format, but no answer...**. In VBA it is not enough to find **a way of doing**. The important issue is to to it in an efficient way. At least, this is my opinion and my way of thinking/working. I have the handicap of not being able to test the code on your specific environment. In fact, I couldn't test it at all. If nothing confidential, can you share the workbook in discussion?

Comment: "What you say makes sense only if you do not want the same row to be returned for the following value to be matched" I do not understand what you mean in this statement. I want every row in "K:K" to have a separate result in Sheets ("Lineups"). No, I do not need the format copied to the new sheet. There is no special formatting, it is just a general cell. And yes, I would love to share the workbook so you can test. What is the best way to share?

Comment: @safo2238 I meant that if a match has been found in a specific row, **that row should be excluded for the future searches**. You can share the workbook sending to my personal mail account (you can find it in my user profile), or using a transfer site. The [next one](https://easyupload.io/) is free and easy to be used.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean! Once a row has been matched it should be excluded from being matched again, perfect way of saying it. I will send it to your email now, along with the two workbooks I get the ranges from.

Comment: @safo2238 What other two workbooks? Does the code process two other workbooks? Please, try explaining (in mail) how do you use the above code in the context of the three workbooks... I must leave the office in about 25 minutes. I will try developing now something without testing it, but I will be able to look at what you sent only after some hours, when I will be at home. And I would also like to  not waste my time deducing how you use them...

Comment: @safo2238 I checked my email and nothing has has been received from the community... (ivangu@yahoo.com).

Comment: I have sent you two emails from safo2238@gmail.com

Comment: @safo2238 I must leave now. I will edit my answer and add an adapted code, which (theoretically) should do what we talked about... Post the new version. Please, send some feeback.

Comment: I am getting an error "Sub or function not defined" on this line of code. `Set rngSearch = inverseintersect(rng, rngExcl.EntireRow)` I believe the `inverseintersect` needs to be defined but I am still learning and don't know what it needs to be defined as.

Comment: @safo2238  Edited the answer and copied the missing function...

Comment: @FanDuru I will need some time to digest this but on initial run I am getting an error on `Set rngExcl = ws.Range("A" & Join(arrExcl, ",A"))` The error says "Method 'Range' Of Object '_Worksheet' failed" Could it be because `arrExcl` is not defined?

Comment: @safo2238 I will post an updated code, in less than 5 minutes. It looks that the range to be excluded increases over 256 characters, which is the maximum allowed. I will use another `Union` range. I will test it on your workbook and send it back, too. In less than 10 minutes...

Comment: @safo2238 Adapted the code and tested on the received workbook. I will send it back, not updated with the data from the other two files. You can do that...

Comment: @FanDuru Absolutely perfect, just what I was looking for. Thank you. Time to break it down and learn some high-quality code. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you explain what the `inverseintersect` code does?

Comment: @safo2238 It excludes from the range to be searched, the rows where already a match has been found. Excel has specific functions for Intersecting ranges (resulting a range composed only from the intersected cells) or making a `Union` which merge ranges, even not being continuous. The function in discussion does exactly the inverse of `Intersect`. It makes a range composed only **from rows which do not intersect**. I will edit its code and place some comments there, to make it more easy to be understood...

Comment: You are very talented, thank you very much. You will be my first choice for advice or help in the future!